# I am missing the Add new item Add "MFC Class From Typelib" in VS-2019

Tags: mfc, com, visual-studio-2019

I have all MFC stuff installed foe my VS-2019 Porfessional.

I miss the Add New Item "MFC Class From Tyspelib" used in former version to create a simple IDispatch wrapper.

I checked everything and I installed the same stuff like in VS-2017. I see this in my VS-2017 version.

What did I miss?

Comment: It looks like MS is trying to kill MFC because with each VS version, MFC related wizards get worse. Fortunately they don't introduce bugs in the MFC library as far as I know at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many Wizards, including that, have been removed from the VS2019.
The release notes say:

> [Deprecations - Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#-deprecations)
>
> - The following C++ ATL/MFC wizards are no longer available: ATL COM+ 1.0 Component Wizard, ATL Active Server Pages Component Wizard, ATL OLE DB Provider Wizard, ATL Property Page Wizard, ATL OLE DB Consumer Wizard, MFC ODBC Consumer, MFC class from ActiveX control, and **MFC class from Type Lib**. Sample code for these technologies is archived at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/) and the [VCSamples GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples).

---

These changes start from VS2017 ver 15.3.
The change began with this edition, but no consistent behavior was completed.
[Add ATL Simple Object in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46522232/9014308)

If you can do what you want with VS2017's latest version 15.9.13, you should work there and port to VS2019.

Furthermore, some work is impossible in 15.9.13. In that case, you need to work with older versions in the following way and port to VS2019

- User registration at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/
- Download and install the product version below if you have a MSDN subscription, otherwise uses the Community version.

  - Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.0) (Note: This should never be updated)
  - Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3

If this is not possible, you will need to do something manually that Wizard did automatically.

Comment: The MSDN documentation is not up to date. Here it states how to add a class from a typelib (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/automation-clients-using-type-libraries?view=msvc-160) but in this link it states that it is removed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/add-class-from-typelib-wizard?view=msvc-160

Comment: As you commented, this answer states that such features are disabled in newer versions of Visual Studio. Your comment will be a repeat of my answer. Therefore, if you want to use such a function, you need to use an older version of Visual Studio that supports it, or the programmer himself needs to scratch code the same source code created by Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This wizard was removed in VS2017 15.3, but then returned in VS2019 16.8. It also available in VS2022.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/typelib-and-activex-now-supported-in-mfc-wizards/

But Microsoft documentation is still outdated. As for now, VS 2019 does not have "Add class from typelib" option at project context menu. Instead, you need to "Add"->"New Item..." and find "MFC Class from Typelib"