# How to add database to MFC project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2017, mfc

I need to create an MFC project with database. As I can see in screens of VS 2015, there was a special option for it. But in VS 2017 I don't see it. Here's the list of components I have:

[image]

But I still can't find anything that can help me find database support for mfc. I will be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked my VS2019, it is gone. When 2017 was released, there were wizards missing for dialogs and they added them back. They did major stuff to the interface into 2017. I would drop the question on MS support. It may or may not do any good.

Comment: According to the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/188667/cmfc-application-wizard-database-support-setting-m.html). It seems a issue in vs2017. As fae as I'm concerned, you could try to directly use CDatabase and CRecordset classes to open to the database, and read/write to the tables, or call SQL using different CRecordset objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will be similar to my answer [I am missing the Add new item Add "MFC Class From Typelib" in VS-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56836205/9014308) or this issue [The big ATL wizard misery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289506/the-big-atl-wizard-misery.html).

You will need to create it in VS2015 and port it to VS2017, or manually implement what the Wizard does automatically.