# Adding an automation method to an existing MFC class

Tags: c++, automation, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I have an MFC application with automation server support. There is an existing class with automation methods...

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CSizeToolDoc, CDocument)
    //{{AFX_DISPATCH_MAP(CSizeToolDoc)
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX(CSizeToolDoc, "ClientGetData", GetClientGetData, SetClientGetData, VT_BOOL)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CSizeToolDoc, "SetActiveArea", SetActiveArea, VT_BOOL, VTS_VARIANT)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CSizeToolDoc, "ShowWindow", ShowWindow, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION(CSizeToolDoc, "GetBoxes", GetBoxes, VT_VARIANT, VTS_NONE)
    ...
    //}}AFX_DISPATCH_MAP
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

I simply need to add a new automation method but I can't locate any documentation describing how to do this and the Class Wizard doesn't seem to provide it either (if I try to add the code manually I'm worried it will break the app because I don't know all the files which would need to be updated).

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019, the Wizard has disappeared due to the situation of this article. [I am missing the Add new item Add "MFC Class From Typelib" in VS-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56836205/9014308) Add functionality manually based on information from existing sources.

Comment: This is an `IDispatch` interface implementation. All you need is add an entry into the dispatch map, and provide an implementation. There aren't any other files you would need to modify. Relevant information: [Automation Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/automation-servers), [Dispatch Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/dispatch-maps), [TN039: MFC/OLE Automation Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn039-mfc-ole-automation-implementation).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I ended up manually adding the method as suggested. One extra step I did was adding the method to an odl file ([id(18)] VARIANT MyNewMethod();). I'm not sure if this was correct or necessary but everything *seems* to be working.

Comment: ODL files are only required, if you plan to compile a TypeLib (see [Type Libraries and the Object Description Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/type-libraries-and-the-object-description-language)). If this is just an application that exposes automation interfaces, you don't need a TypeLib. An `IDispatch` interface works without any additional metadata. Everything a client needs to query for and invoke its services is exposed through the [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch).