# Visual Studio MFC C++ "CFormView" Missing from "base class" drop down

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, c++14, c++17

I am a beginner learning Visual Studio 2019 Community. Specifically MFC C++.

It is challenging as I am struggling to find good reference material and examples. Youtube has been very helpful for tutorials and examples. However, all the information I have found are using earlier versions of Visual Studio which are not a step by step process. I have found myself doing additional research or experimenting to find the same tool used in the example.

My current issue is the example creates a new class with the base class type of "CFormView". However no such value exists in my version of Visual Studio.

With that being said. I have two questions.

1. Please advise on how to create a CformView class in VS.
2. Is there any good quick learning guides for MFC in VS 2019? It would be great to have tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good documentation on MFC is hard to come by, unfortunately. Some of this is due to age and it being supplanted by different frameworks and languages in the Microsoft ecosystem. Not much MFC support seems to trickle out of Redmond these days. On the third party front, it just doesn't seem to be hip. Community support suffers as a result.

Comment: Regarding the question, requests for tutorials are strictly off topic. You're better off muddling your way through with what you can find and then ask questions about why what you've tried doesn't work or asking at Code Review about how to make what you have better. This was the sort of problem Stack Overflow Documentation was supposed to help with. Real shame it didn't work out.

Comment: For a beginner with VC++ with Visual Studio and using MFC;  MSDN is a useful source of information. Explore [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/windows/overview-of-windows-programming-in-cpp?view=vs-2019) for more info. Also see the samples at [VC++ samples on github](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples). With some overview about MFC, you can explore more about [CFormView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cformview-class?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 1):

VS2017 and VS2019 have become difficult development environments to continue program development with MFC/ATL.
If you want Wizard-guided development as you've seen in previous books and resources, the best shortcut is to go back to VS2015 and port the results to VS2017 or VS2019.

I have similar answers to similar questions several times.
For example, see these answers and their links.
[How to add database to MFC project in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58400749/9014308)
[I am missing the Add new item Add "MFC Class From Typelib" in VS-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56836205/9014308)
[The big ATL wizard misery.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289506/the-big-atl-wizard-misery.html)
[Deprecations - Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#-deprecations)
[Add ATL Simple Object in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46522232/9014308)
[Changes to Project Templates and Code Wizards in 15.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/08/15/changes-to-project-templates-and-code-wizards-in-15-3/)
[Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.3)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. This was helpful. Based on this. I think I'm going to drop MFC and switch over to Qt. Cheers!